# Como Mostrar todos os elementos de um array declarados numa struct em C?

Tags: c, struct, scanf

Nesse código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct cadastro {
   char nome[50];
   int idade;
   char rua[50];
   int numero;

   };
int main()
{
struct cadastro c[4]; //Array[4] de estruturas
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    gets(c[i].nome);
    scanf("%d", &c[i].idade);
    gets(c[i].rua);
    scanf("%d", &c[i].numero);
}
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Como dar print em todas os elementos da struct, sem fazer manualmente com um printf.
Pois ele irá exibir quatro vezes.

Comment: Acho que o título esta mal formulado.

Comment: Sugestão 1: não uses `gets()`; é impossível usar essa função com segurança; a função foi removida do Standard de C em 2011; substitui por `fgets()`. Sugestão 2: não mistures `fgets()` (`gets()`) com `scanf()`; usa sempre `fgets()` e, se necessário, `sscanf()`.

Comment: @pmg Estou lendo a versão do C99.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para imprimir todos os elementos duma só vez, com uma única instrução simples, usa 1 função!

```
void cadastro_print(struct cadastro *p) {
    printf("nome: %s\n", p->nome);
    printf("idade: %d\n", p->idade);
    printf("rua: %s\n", p->rua);
    printf("numero: %d\n", p->numero);
    printf("\n");
}
```

e, na `main()`, chama essa função

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) cadastro_print(c + i);
```

Comment: Tive que colocar --std=c11
no meu compilador

Comment: O problema da leitura é da mistura de `gets()` com `scanf()`. O `scanf()` deixa o ENTER "pendurado" e o `gets()` seguinte apanha a linha vazia.

Comment: Por que o fgets lê com \n?, ta certo? http://pastebin.com/DnPnADBV

Comment: Mas tem erro nisso, não imprime corretamente, não lê as variáveis corretamente.

Comment: Fiz uma versão com `fgets()` e tirando o ENTER final: http://ideone.com/tNkSdH

Comment: Mas e a versão c99 do ideone?, ok.

Comment: Passa a definicao de variavel do `for` para fora do ciclo, para o principio do bloco, e o programa passa a ser C89 `for (int i = 0; ...)` passa a `int i; for (i = 0; ...)`

Comment: Mas programar em versões antigas do C, não é pior?, declarara variável i(int) antes do for é considerado ruim?

Comment: Ainda há compiladores que não foram actualizados para C99, muito menos C11. Se tens de usar um desses compiladores, tens de usar C89. Além disso algumas das novidades das novas versões são quase apenas "açucar sintáctico" :)

Comment: Estou usando o gcc compiler, e o codeblocks. mas há como definir opções de compilação.

Comment: O gcc tem parametros para definir a linguagem: `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic ...` ou `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic ...` ou `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic ...`; não conheço o codeblocks.

Comment: Sim, defini --std=c11 em compilador, do codeblocks, porque antes não aceitava declarar a variável no for.

Comment: Obrigado, agora já esta funcionando corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, acho que não ficou bem claro o que você quis perguntar.

Primeiro que não existe método mais recomendado pra output de valores em C do que com printf.

Para imprimir os nomes, basta seguir a mesma lógica que você usou para lê-los:

```
for (i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("%s\n",c[i].nome);
}
```

Comment: Declarar uma função não seria melhor?....

Comment: O algoritmo a ser usado independe de estar dentro de uma função ou não. Isso já vai do teu gosto.